# React Native + Firebase : How to use Facebook authentication

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I started building an app with React Native and am in the process of implementing a firebase backend.

I added the standard login with firebase, but now having issue when implementing the facebook authentication. I'm unable to access the FacebookAuthProvider mentionned in the documentation.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider

They give two contradictory examples, and neither seems to work. In the first, it is instantiated:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
```

When I try to invoke this, I get an error.

> 12-23 19:14:07.388  3082  3517 E ReactNativeJS: undefined is not a
>   constructor (evaluating 'new
>   _Firebase2.default.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()')

And a few lines below they give the following example:

```
var cred = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(...)
```

Where it's being accessed as a static object and not a constructor. This also does not seem to work. I have difficulty understanding how the Firebase API actually works given those two examples, and I still don't have a functional FB authentication for my app. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: please show the code

Answer (score 1):

This isn't clearly explained in the Firebase API but it seems that there's a clear distinction between the API provided by an instantiated FirebaseApp and the API provided by the Firebase module.

My mistake was that I was trying to access the FacebookAuthProvider through my FirebaseApp instead of the actual Firebase module. I now changed the reference and everything seems to be working.